# TimePicker time columns are reversed

Tags: objective-c, datetimepicker

I want to have a time picker in my application, the problem is that the hours and minutes column is misplaced - meaning they changed places, as shown in the attached image.

Here's my `onViewDidLoad()`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    self.titleBackgroudView.backgroundColor = self.isOn ? ChromagenSwitchOnRedColor: ChromagenSwitchOnGreenColor;
    self.titleLabel.text = self.isOn ? [PListHelper localizedStringForKey:@"ssrTimerOff"] : [PListHelper localizedStringForKey:@"ssrTimerOn"];

    [self.applyButton setTitle:[PListHelper localizedStringForKey:@"applyButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.applyButton setTitleColor:self.isOn ? ChromagenSwitchOnRedColor: ChromagenSwitchOnGreenColor  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.cancelButton setTitle:[PListHelper localizedStringForKey:@"cancelButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:self.isOn ? ChromagenSwitchOnRedColor : ChromagenSwitchOnGreenColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"appLanguage"] containsString:@"en"]){

        [self.datePicker setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    }

}
```

Even though I try to change the locale, the order of the columns still remains mm:HH instead of HH:mm. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**
I also tried the following:

```
self.datePicker.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
```

But I also didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this code in the ViewController:

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSArray* subviews = [self.datePicker subviews];
    for(UIView* subview in subviews){
        [subview setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    }

}
```